# What part of the foot do you hit the ball with when juggling a football?

Tags: football, technique

What exact part of the foot do you use to hit the ball. I've heard  that you should not juggle with the toes, so should you hit it with the instep, the soft side of the foot or the one slightly below the ankle which is a bit harder? It would be a great help if a picture or video is shown. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert but from years of experience I would say between the hard part of the top of your foot and your toes. So approximately near the balls of your feet.

Personally though, I would say just practice holding the ball in two hands and dropping in onto your feet, trying to kick it gently back up to your hands while generating backspin. I think once you can continuously get this backspin on in, you should have found the correct place to make contact with the ball.

Also don't forget to practice this with both feet as it will improve your control/ touch, balance and feel for the ball.